# Visual Studio nuget not install packages

Tags: visual-studio, entity-framework-core, nuget-package

When I try to add dependencies to my new project it does not work. I receive the following error:

```
PM> Install-Package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer
Restoring packages for E:\CProjects\BlazorApp1\BlazorApp1\BlazorApp1.csproj...
  GET https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.relational/index.json
  OK https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.relational/index.json 297ms

.. remove some sucessful operartions..


  OK https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.analyzers/index.json 256ms
  GET https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.analyzers/8.0.0/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.analyzers.8.0.0.nupkg
  OK https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.analyzers/8.0.0/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.analyzers.8.0.0.nupkg 36ms
Install-Package : **Access to the path 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Analyzers.dll' is denied.**
At line:1 char:1
+ Install-Package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PackageManagement.PowerShellCmdlets.InstallPackageCommand
```

What is going wrong?
Thanks in advance.

Simply I tried to install new dependencies through Nuget package manager as I did before, but it does not work.

Comment: What's the .net version of the project?

Comment: "Access to the path 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Analyzers.dll' is denied" suggests a permission issue, or that something is keeping that file in use. Try restarting Visual Studio.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, something was locking my file but it was not VS it was .NET.
For some reason I have never restarted my PC, just left in Sleep mode and after your useful answers I track what was locking my file and that solved my problem.
I was surprised that it was possible.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).